# Why does $_Exception have no content after a failed Invoke-RestMethod call?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to capture the error response when making an Invoke-RestMethod call in PowerShell. The code gets to the catch block, but the $_Exception property is always empty.

I found this code on another question, however it does not work. There is never any data in any of these variables.

```
    catch [System.Net.WebException] {   
         $respStream = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
         $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($respStream)
         $respBody = $reader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
         Write-Host "Response is $respBody." #$respBody is empty
         $_Exception #$_Exception is empty
    }
```

I invoke my request like this: `$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$root_url$url" -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body $json`

If I don't have the try/catch, the failed response (ex 400) JSON will be outputted to the console, so I know PowerShell sees it, but I can't figure out where it is putting it when I try to access it in a catch block.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should use `$_.Exception` (notice the dot)

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked. Adding `$respStream.Position = 0` resolved my issue.